Flutter Firebase Auth Redirection Not Working After Login When Previously Logged In and Then Logged Out
I'm working on a Flutter app with Firebase Authentication, and after logging out and trying to log back in, the user remains stuck on the LoginPage until a hot restart, at which point the redirection works correctly.
Problem Description:

When the app is launched for the first time, and the user logs in, the redirection works as expected — the user is redirected to the HomePage.
After logging out, when I attempt to log in again, the app remains on the LoginPage without redirecting to the HomePage.
After performing a hot restart, the redirection works correctly and the user is redirected to the HomePage.
Additionally, the login only works once after the hot restart, and subsequent login attempts do not trigger the redirection, leaving the user stuck on the login page.

My main.dart calls auth.dart home: const AuthPage(),
auth.dart:
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mini_social_app/auth/login_or_register.dart';
import 'package:mini_social_app/pages/home_page.dart';
class AuthPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const AuthPage({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          // when user logged in
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return const HomePage();
          }
          //when user is logged out
          else {
            return const LoginOrRegister();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

login.dart:
  void login(BuildContext context) async {
    // display the loading circle
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ),
    );

    // try sign-in
    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: mailController.text,
        password: passwordController.text,
      );

      // pop the loading circle
      if (context.mounted) Navigator.of(context).pop();
      print('login : sign-in');
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      // pop the loading circle
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
      displayErrorMessageToUser(e.code, context);
    }
  }

Expected Behavior:
After logging in and logging out, the user should be redirected to the HomePage without needing a hot restart.
Current Behavior:
After logging out and attempting to log back in, the app stays on the LoginPage. A hot restart is required to trigger the correct redirection. After the restart, the login works only once, and subsequent attempts keep the user on the LoginPage.
I implemented Firebase Authentication in my Flutter app, using authStateChanges() to handle user login and redirection. I created an AuthPage with a FutureBuilder that listens to the authStateChanges() stream. The app is supposed to redirect to the HomePage if the user is logged in, and to the LoginOrRegister page if the user is logged out.
I tested the app in the following scenarios:

Logging in for the first time works as expected, redirecting to the HomePage.
After logging out and trying to log in again, the app stays on the LoginPage and does not redirect to the HomePage.
A hot restart fixes the redirection, sending the user to the HomePage.
After a hot restart, the app logs the user in only once, and subsequent login attempts do not trigger the redirection, leaving the user stuck on the LoginPage.

here is the link of the repo: https://github.com/julienBelinga/mini-social-app/tree/dev

Looks to me like your code is only observing the first update (literally using the first property) from the authStateChanges stream and ignoring every subsequent change.  If you want to receive updates from all auth state changes (including the situation you describe), then you need to listen to all of the updates as shown in the documentation.  So, you will need to handle a stream, not a single future.

Sorry, I originally showed my new code where I was trying new stuff; I've edited back the question with my original code where there is no code, but the issue is still there.
